PyAudio installtion errors
I am trying to install PyAudio into visual studio code for a project I'm working on, but every way I try get errors.
I am using Python 3.10.6 on Windows 11. I first tried using pip install PyAudio but got the following errors:
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pyaudio)

Then I tried downloading PyAudio as a wheel directly from here. I specifically downloaded the file
"PyAudio-0.2.14-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl", since I'm using 3.10.6 and 64 bit Python and Windows.
I then got the error:
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.14-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

The other forums and videos I have tried looking at all use Christopher Gohkle's unofficial website, but that has since been removed. If anyone could please help me figure a way to install it. Thanks!
